# How to detect window resize in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I'm working on a TUI (Text User Interface) library for C++, and I have a function for detecting the size of the console window. Is it possible for me to detect a window resize? I would prefer if it would work with any terminal emulator, but if it matters I am using Ubuntu Budgie 20.10, and my terminal emulator is Tilix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way by constantly checking the screen size. If the screen size changes, it will be recorded and the screen redrawn.

Answer (score 4):

You can [set up a signal handler for the `SIGWINCH` signal](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), and you will get this signal whenever the terminal size changes. Note that, as with all signal handlers, any code in the signal handler must be signal-safe.

If you are using the curses library, you will get a `KEY_RESIZE` key, and then check `COLS` and `LINES`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I would also like to point out, that I am not using curses/ncurses, I'm using ASCII escape codes to control it.